# Styling polymer paper-dropdown-menu scrollbar

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to change the look of the scrollbar inside the dropdown menu of a paper-dropdown-menu. Here is my html:

```
<body>
    <paper-dropdown-menu id="series" name="series" label="Series">
      <paper-menu id="seriesDD" class="dropdown-content">
        <?php
          for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
            echo '<paper-item>'.$i.'</paper-item>';
          }
        ?>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <div style="height:9000px"></div>
</body>
```

And here is my css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 6px;}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:rgb(196, 196, 196); border-radius: 5px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background-color:rgb(196, 196, 196);}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

This does style the window's scrollbar but leaves the paper-dropdown-menu's scrollbar untouched. How can I make this css also affect the dropdown menu?

Comment: you would need custom properties or mixin but they are currently lacking...